# Help with Fourier Series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^{2k}}\sin{2\pi j x}$

Tags: fourier-series, bernoulli-polynomials

I've found the limit of a similar expression in the literature (Abramowitz &  Stegun), which uses Bernoulli polynomials:

$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^{2k+1}}\sin{2\pi j x}=\frac{-(-1)^k(2\pi)^{2k+1}}{2(2k+1)}B_{2k+1}(x)$

My question is, how about the below, does it also have a known limit? (**The aforementioned reference doesn't have it.**)

$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^{2k}}\sin{2\pi j x}$

I would guess not, but unlikely. Reason is cause this is similar to the non-existence of closed-forms for say $\zeta(2k+1)$ as opposed to $\zeta(2k)$, but need to confirm. (Yes, searching the literature for the novelty of things is one of the most challenging tasks.)

Comment: You are just dealing with the real/imaginary part of $\text{Li}_{m}(e^{2\pi i x})$.

Comment: Is there an integral representation for it?

Comment: Of course, but it is kind of tautological. You may compute the $(n+1)$-th Bernoulli polynomial by integrating the $n$-th Bernoulli polynomial and choosing the suitable constant. The same happens here.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Would you mind demonstrating how that's done in an answer? ;)